# Magento1.9.3 - Sagepay show 404 on mobile place order

Tags: magento-1.9, sagepay

i am getting error 404 on order place on mobile screen only on

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with older verisons of the extension.
Adding the version number for the extension in use helps a lot into finding the cause of the problem.

Regards,
Santiago.